# Issue after WordPress update

Tags: updates

After a recent WP update I get this error message in the back-end. Front-end is working without issues:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_filter() on array in /...
>   /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 111

I already tried updating WP manually but the issue persists. Ideas anyone?

Comment: Can you please copy the code from the php file that is causing the issue? line 111, and preferably a few lines before and after.

Comment: This is line 106 to 113

function add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 ) {
 global $wp_filter;
 if ( ! isset( $wp_filter[ $tag ] ) ) {
  $wp_filter[ $tag ] = new WP_Hook();
 }
 $wp_filter[ $tag ]->add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
 return true;
}

Line 111 is this

$wp_filter[ $tag ]->add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );

Comment: OMG the formating is horrible...

Comment: I made a screenshot...sorry

[link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4814298/code.png)

Comment: No problem. you can use ` to start the code and ` again to end code formatting.

Comment: Another try

`function add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority = 10, $accepted_args = 1 ) {
 global $wp_filter;
 if ( ! isset( $wp_filter[ $tag ] ) ) {
  $wp_filter[ $tag ] = new WP_Hook();
 }
 $wp_filter[ $tag ]->add_filter( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
 return true;
}`

Comment: Doesn´t get better but I guess you got it ;-)

Comment: I assume you are using WordPress Multilingual plugin?

Comment: That´s right. I´m using WPML (http://www.bankingombudsman.ch/)

Comment: That's a problem from a plugin, not from the core. You should rename the plugin folder, login again, now all plugins are deactivated and test with each plugin, from which is the error fired.

Comment: Thanks Frank, you saved my evening. I didn´t assume it´s a plugins issue because I didn´t update a plugin but I updated WP core. Anyway now it works again :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official support thread, you can:

- Check out if you have the latest version downloaded and installed on your website. Head over to `My Account -> Downloads` on your [WPML account](https://wpml.org/account/downloads/).
- If you need help updating, you can check [this](http://wpml.org/faq/install-wpml/#2) out.
- If none of the above helped you, consider submitting a support ticket on the [WPML support forums](https://wpml.org/forums/forum/english-support/).

Now that we are off the official guidelines, we can stick to our own methods.

Try disabling the WPML plugin via ftp, or fully move the folder to somewhere else just to see if you can login to back-end.

If you can't use ftp, you can use [WordPress command lines](http://wp-cli.org/) to deactivate the plugin.

After that you can login to back-end and install or update the WPML plugin to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes I have the latest version of WPML. Anyway I deactivated the plugin via FTP but the issue still persists. I can´t use my back-end and now that the WPML plugin is deactivated also the front-end looks like a total mess :-(

Comment: @MichaelOeser You can enable it again via WPCL. The problem is because of WPML anyway. If this general guide didn't help, perhaps you should submit a ticket there.

Comment: I removed all plugins and was able to enter the back-end. WordPress was updated to the latest version and I re-activated most of the plugins incl. WPML. No issues whatsoever. So WPML seems NOT to be the bad guy. Seems as if exec-PHP causes the issues (which hasn´t been updated since several years)

Comment: Good to hear you could fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a WPML problem. For everybody who needs to fix it without updating WMPL there is a way.

Just rename:

`/wp-contents/plugins/installer`

to

`/wp-contents/plugins/_installer`

Then the Problem goes away. Ok, it's a hot fix but it works.